# brickwall infra white noise generator

Tags: white-noise

I would like to generate brickwall low pass filtered white noise. a cutoff of 1/n is fine for integer n. I suspect that I could mess around with samples that are convolved with the sinc function, but I hope there is a better way? preferably would like to keep the HF noise less than the dither level or if not possible then maby 2x or 4x.

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done as stated.

Brick-wall filters have an impulse response that's infinitely long in both time directions, i.e. it is also infinitely non-causal. That can't be implemented.

Other than that the question comes down to a standard low-pass filter design process. You need to specify your requirements in terms of cutoff frequency, passband ripple, transition band width, stop band attenuation, phase distortion, causality, transient preservation, time domain ringing, memory and CPU cost, etc. The "best" filter will be determined by doing the best trade-off between these requirements for your specific application.

This being said, since you want to create noise, you probably don't care much about time domain artifacts and phase distortions, so chances are an IIR filter may work well here, specifically when $n$ gets large and the cutoff very low.

Comment: I don't think the OP means a mathematical brick wall.  He/she can Kaiser window a long sinc function and it will be pretty bricky.

Comment: Sure, but again that's a standard low pass filter design: Optimize for your specific requirements and constraints. People frequently use "brick-wall" to mean "perfect in all aspects", which you can't have.

Comment: I use *"brickwall LPF"* whenever I mean a sinc impulse response.  If it's a windowed sinc that's good n long, it's still a pretty solid brick wall.

Comment: I didn't ask for a perfect brickwall, I simply asked to keep HF noise down close to quantization levels so that we can best approximate a brickwall?

Comment: for example, with the IIR based approach, if you randomly selected a chunk of n samples where n is the ratio of the nyquist to cutoff frequency, you'd see a bias to not prefer the very top band? supposing that doesn't matter, how do I construct said IIR, so that the FFT of an impulse would have the bands above the cutoff to have a magnitude near enough to the quantization levels?

Comment: my thinking is the following: this is generative so delay is irrelevant, and eventually the sinc function should go below the quantization level, so it becomes irrelevant?

Comment: @micsthepick Just convolve with a windowed Sinc function as RBJ suggested which is an FIR filter. Kaiser window is an excellent choice.  So generate white noise samples using any decent random number generator and then pass that through the FIR filter whose coefficients are the Sinc function (as long as you can tolerate) multiplied by a Kaiser window.

Comment: thinking back on this - why is it that we need to use a brick wall filter? This is asking how to generate white noise that has a specific shape, we don't need to start with general white noise?

Comment: You do not need to use a brick wall filter (a term that's typically used to refer to a an ideal lowpass filter). Just use a lowpass filter that meets your specific requirements. IN most cases defining cutoff, width of the transition band and amount of stop band attenuation will be enough to pick an appropriate filter . You just can't have an instant transition from pass band to stop band